# Byte manipulation does not work with unsigned char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I tried to experiment with bit manipulations on a byte.
At first I tried to say that I have `1111 1111` (256) and `1000 0000`(128).
So I do this:

```
printf("%u\n", 256 & 128);
```

I expect to get `128` but I get `0`.

So I tried:

```
printf("%u\n", ((unsigned char) 256) & ((unsigned char) 128));
```

But that gives me the same result.

What is wrong with that?

Comment: 11111111 is not 256 but 255

Comment: Decimal 256 is out-of-bounds for an unsigned char.

Comment: Question morphed, making comments and answer/s inappropriate, so down and close voting.

Comment: @MartinJames you are right. I reversed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1111 1111`  is `255`

So try

```
printf("%u\n", 255 & 128);
               ^^^
```

Take into account that the type of the integer constants `255` and `128` is `int`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake :( sorry